# Ошибка при создании проекта в Maven с использованием архетипа webapp

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, maven

При создании проекта в `IntelijIdea` на `Maven` использую архетип `maven-archetype-webapp`. После того, как прописываю названия `GroupId`, `ArtefactId` и `ProjectName` открывается сам проект, но:

Во первых нет структуры папок;

Во вторых выдает в консоли ошибку:

```java
Error: Could not find or load main class ���
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ���
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создайте проект без архитипа.

Comment: Вы точно дожидаетесь конца подгрузки проекта?

Comment: Да, конечно! Ошибка выдается сразу после того, как все подгрузится.

Comment: А как без архетипа создать, если он мне требуется?